# how to continue recording to the same audio file through different pages using phonegap?

Tags: cordova, asynchronous, audio-recording

I need my **phonegap** app to have audio recording in the background while its working. For that, the `Media` object works just fine, the thing is it stops recording once I'm navigating to a new page. I didn't find any way to pause and continue the recording, and even if possible I'd rather not do that since the recording will be cut.

Do I need to start writing plugins?

```
function startAudioRec() {
  var src = "rec.amr";
  audioRec = new Media(src, recordOnSuccess, recordOnError);
  audioRec.startRecord();
  circleBlink();
  console.log("test");

}
function recordOnError() {}
function recordOnSuccess() {}

var visible = true;
var recInterval;

function circleBlink() {
  recInterval = setInterval(blink, 1000);
  function blink() {
    var circle = document.getElementById('recCircle');
    if (visible) {
      circle.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
      visible = false;
    } else {
      circle.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible;");
      visible = true;
    }
  }
}
function stopAudioRec() {
  audioRec.stopRecord();
  clearInterval(recInterval);
  document.getElementById("recCircle").setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
  audioRec.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a framework like Dojo and build your application as a [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Then when you navigate to a new page, it will basically take care of swapping out the DOM elements for you. In theory you are staying on the same HTML page so it should not stop recording until you tell it to. Just an idea though...this is an interesting question, do let us know what you end up doing. Good luck!

Here is a simple example of a single page app built in Dojo: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileSlideShow/demo.html

There are more in the app tests: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dojox/app/tests/  Not all of them are single page web apps. I know other frameworks will do this for you that might be easier to learn, sorry I don't have any links though.

Comment: eventually I have implemented SPA using knockoutJS. apparently, screen lock also stops the recording, so I had to disable it too. all this tricks kind of make me feel like a hack, audio recording in the background suppose to be pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

so far my only idea is to dynamycally remove all the html elements and replace them on the same page using javascript and DOM, thus staying on the same page in the entire application without navigating at all. something better anyone? i would like to be able to navigate, my solution isnt intuative.

```
    var page1=document.getElementsByName("page1");
    var size=page1.length;
    for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
        page1.removeChild(page1[0]);
    }
    var a=document.createElement("button");
    a.setAttribute("name","page2");
```